# document.getElementsByClassName(...).data is not a function

Tags: jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
            alert(1)
            var stopMusicExt = document.getElementsByClassName('shopcart').data();
            alert(data);
            alert(stopMusicExt);
}
```

//Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).data is not a function

Comment: The [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) returned from [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) doesn't have that method defined. Are you trying to use jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method?

Comment: _checkout.html:191 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at _checkout.html:191

Comment: That means `data` either hasn't been declared as a variable or isn't accessible within this function. [ReferenceError: "x" is not defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined)

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names so you have to specify which one you want, like this: `document.getElementsByClassName('shopcart')[0].data()`. See [reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).